# Is there a way to merge two pipe de-limted Csv files in mule 4 using dataweave 2.0 in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to insert the below pipe delimited row of csv into 1st row of another pipe delimited csv.

First pipe delimited file:

```
000000001|0|0|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF||||
```

Second pipe delimited payload looks like this:

```
00000002|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4||||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449|  
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6||||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
000000004|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6||||65000545664123|35463||J1||||MW09449|
```

Is there a way to merge both into one?

Comment: Please list the things that you have already tried, so that we don't waste time telling you to repeat them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read both files as just text/plain and then concatenate them. If you need the final result as CSV, or something you can transform, you can do something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
read(firstFile ++ "\n" ++ secondFile, "application/csv",{ separator: "|", header: false})
```